# Create a calculated column based on columns that are from current row and previous row

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have complicated logic to implement, tried for some time but still no clue, please help to check if it's realistic to do and how to do. thank you very much!!

I have following `SparkSQL` dataframe (`datetime` is increasing, 'type' is recurring, every section (different type) always starts with `'flag'=1`, ):

```
+---------+-----+----+-----+
|datetime |type |flag|value|
+---------+-----+----+-----+
|20170901 |A    |1   |  560|
|20170902 |A    |0   | 3456|
|20170903 |A    |0   |   50|
|20170904 |A    |0   |  789|
......
|20170912 |B    |1   |  345|
|20170913 |B    |0   | 4510|
|20170915 |B    |0   |  508|
......
|20170919 |C    |1   |   45|
|20170923 |C    |0   |  410|
|20170925 |C    |0   |  108|
......
|20171001 |A    |1   |  198|
|20171002 |A    |0   |  600|
|20171005 |A    |0   |  675|
|20171008 |A    |0   |  987|
......
```

I need to create a calculated column based on previous row and current row, to have dataframe like this (calculated field-Seq means increasing section sequence ):

```
+---------+-----+----+-----+-----+
|datetime |type |flag|value|  Seq|
+---------+-----+----+-----+-----+
|20170901 |A    |1   |  560|    1|
|20170902 |A    |0   | 3456|    1|
|20170903 |A    |0   |   50|    1|
|20170904 |A    |0   |  789|    1|
......
|20170912 |B    |1   |  345|    2|
|20170913 |B    |0   | 4510|    2|
|20170915 |B    |0   |  508|    2|
......
|20170919 |C    |1   |   45|    3|
|20170923 |C    |0   |  410|    3|
|20170925 |C    |0   |  108|    3|
......
|20171001 |A    |1   |  198|    4|
|20171002 |A    |0   |  600|    4|
|20171005 |A    |0   |  675|    4|
|20171008 |A    |0   |  987|    4|
......
```

any clues are appreciated.
I wrote code (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1592191/mrsrinivas):

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
import sys

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]")
conf = conf.setAppName("test")
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
rdd = sc.parallelize([(20170901,"A",1,560), (20170902,"A",0,3560), (20170903,"A",0,50), (20170904,"A",0,56), 
                      (20170912,"B",1,345), (20170913,"B",0,4510), (20170915,"B",0,453),
                      (20170919,"C",1,55), (20170923,"C",0,410), (20170925,"C",0,108),
                      (20171001,"A",1,189), (20171002,"A",0,600), (20171005,"A",0,650), (20171008,"A",0,956)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, ["datatime", "type", "flag", "value"])
df.show()

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(df['type']).orderBy(df['flag'].desc()).rangeBetween(-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize)
df.withColumn('Seq', func.dense_rank().over(windowSpec))
df.show()
```

but met error: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o514.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window Frame RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING must match the required frame ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW;
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```python
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, monotonically_increasing_id, when, last
import sys

#sample data
df = sc.parallelize([(20170901,"A",1,560), (20170902,"A",0,3560), (20170903,"A",0,50), (20170904,"A",0,56),
                     (20170912,"B",1,345), (20170913,"B",0,4510), (20170915,"B",0,453),
                     (20170919,"C",1,55), (20170923,"C",0,410), (20170925,"C",0,108),
                     (20171001,"A",1,189), (20171002,"A",0,600), (20171005,"A",0,650), (20171008,"A",0,956)]).\
    toDF(["datetime", "type", "flag", "value"])

df = df.withColumn("row_id",monotonically_increasing_id())
w = Window.partitionBy(col("type")).orderBy(col('datetime'))
df1 = df.withColumn("seq_temp", when(col('flag')==1, col('row_id')).otherwise(None))
df1 = df1.withColumn("seq", last('seq_temp', True).over(w.rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))).\
    drop('row_id','seq_temp').\
    sort('Seq')
df1.show()
```

Output is:

```
+--------+----+----+-----+----------+
|datetime|type|flag|value|       seq|
+--------+----+----+-----+----------+
|20170901|   A|   1|  560|         0|
|20170902|   A|   0| 3560|         0|
|20170903|   A|   0|   50|         0|
|20170904|   A|   0|   56|         0|
|20170913|   B|   0| 4510|         4|
|20170912|   B|   1|  345|         4|
|20170915|   B|   0|  453|         4|
|20170919|   C|   1|   55|8589934592|
|20170925|   C|   0|  108|8589934592|
|20170923|   C|   0|  410|8589934592|
|20171001|   A|   1|  189|8589934595|
|20171008|   A|   0|  956|8589934595|
|20171005|   A|   0|  650|8589934595|
|20171002|   A|   0|  600|8589934595|
+--------+----+----+-----+----------+
```

`seq` value is not in perfect sequence but monotonically increasing.

Comment: thank you very much Prem! it works well, doesn't matter how big the seq number is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code, I have modified it to have "A" twice

```
    from pyspark.sql.window import Window
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col, monotonically_increasing_id, when, last
    from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
    import sys
    import pyspark.sql.functions as func

    #sample data
    df = sc.parallelize([(20170901,"A",1,560), (20170902,"A",0,3560), (20170903,"A",0,50), (20170904,"A",0,56),
                         (20170912,"B",1,345), (20170913,"B",0,4510), (20170915,"B",0,453),
                         (20170919,"C",1,55), (20170923,"C",0,410), (20170925,"C",0,108),
                         (20171001,"A",1,189), (20171002,"A",0,600), (20171005,"A",0,650), (20171008,"A",0,956)]).\
        toDF(["datetime", "type", "flag", "value"])

    df = df.withColumn("row_id",monotonically_increasing_id())
    w = Window.partitionBy(col("type")).orderBy(col('datetime'))
    df1 = df.withColumn("seq_temp", when(col('flag')==1, col('row_id')).otherwise(None))
    df1 = df1.withColumn("seq", last('seq_temp', True).over(w.rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))).sort('Seq')
    r = df1.withColumn('seq_item',lit(0))
    windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(r['seq_item']).orderBy(r['seq'])
    s = r.withColumn('seq_1',func.dense_rank().over(windowSpec)).drop('seq_temp','seq','seq_item','row_id')
    s.show()

+--------+----+----+-----+--------+-----+
|datatime|type|flag|value|seq_item|seq_1|
+--------+----+----+-----+--------+-----+
|20170901|   A|   1|  560|       0|    1|
|20170902|   A|   0| 3560|       0|    1|
|20170903|   A|   0|   50|       0|    1|
|20170904|   A|   0|   56|       0|    1|
|20170912|   B|   1|  345|       0|    2|
|20170913|   B|   0| 4510|       0|    2|
|20170915|   B|   0|  453|       0|    2|
|20170919|   C|   1|   55|       0|    3|
|20170923|   C|   0|  410|       0|    3|
|20170925|   C|   0|  108|       0|    3|
|20171001|   A|   1|  189|       0|    4|
|20171002|   A|   0|  600|       0|    4|
|20171005|   A|   0|  650|       0|    4|
|20171008|   A|   0|  956|       0|    4|
+--------+----+----+-----+--------+-----+
```

Comment: thanks. but the 4th section (column 'type') is 'A' not 'D', which makes it complicated.